# For what $p$ and $k$ (where $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$) is this algebraic expression divisible by $3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.  Denote the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, and the *aliquot sum* of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$.  (Note that, trivially, we have the identity $D(x)+s(x)=x$.)  Finally, denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Let $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ be a prime number (satisfying $\gcd(p,m)=1$, where $m$ is a positive integer), and let $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ be a positive integer.  Hereinafter, let $p^k m$ be a [*deficient number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficient_number).

In a [recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4207460), I proved that
$$D(p^k)D(m) - 2s(p^k)s(m) = 2p^k m - \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m).$$

Now consider the identity
$$p^k m = (D(p^k) + s(p^k))(D(m) + s(m)).$$
This can be rewritten as
$$p^k m = D(p^k)D(m) + s(p^k)s(m) + D(p^k)s(m) + s(p^k)D(m),$$
or as
$$p^k m = 3s(p^k)s(m) + \bigg(D(p^k)D(m) - 2s(p^k)s(m)\bigg) + D(p^k)s(m) + s(p^k)D(m).$$
Equivalently, we have
$$p^k m = 3s(p^k)s(m) + \bigg(2p^k m - \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m)\bigg) + \bigg(\dfrac{p^{k+1} - 2p^k + 1}{p - 1}\bigg)\cdot(\sigma(m) - m) + \bigg(\dfrac{p^k - 1}{p - 1}\bigg)\cdot(2m - \sigma(m))$$
$$= 3s(p^k)s(m) + m\cdot\Bigg(2p^k - \bigg(\dfrac{p^{k+1} - 2p^k + 1}{p - 1}\bigg) + 2\cdot\bigg(\dfrac{p^k - 1}{p - 1}\bigg)\Bigg)$$
$$+ \sigma(m)\cdot\Bigg(\bigg(\dfrac{1 - p^{k+1}}{p - 1}\bigg) + \bigg(\dfrac{p^{k+1} - 2p^k + 1}{p - 1}\bigg) - \bigg(\dfrac{p^k - 1}{p - 1}\bigg)\Bigg),$$
whence we obtain
$$p^k m = 3s(p^k)s(m) + m\cdot\bigg(\dfrac{p^{k+1} + 2p^k - 3}{p - 1}\bigg) + \sigma(m)\cdot\Bigg(-3\bigg(\dfrac{p^k - 1}{p - 1}\bigg)\Bigg)$$
$$= 3s(p^k)s(m) - 3s(p^k)\sigma(m) + m\cdot\bigg(\dfrac{p^{k+1} + 2p^k - 3}{p - 1}\bigg).$$

Here is my question:

> For what primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and positive integers $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is the algebraic expression
> $$C(p,k):=\dfrac{p^{k+1} + 2p^k - 3}{p - 1}$$
> divisible by $3$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Like in the hyperlinked question, since $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $p \neq 3$.  Therefore, either $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.  (Note that $k$ is odd.)

**Case 1:** When $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, the numerator is divisible by $3$, while the denominator is also divisible by $3$.  *Hence, I cannot conclude whether $3 \mid C(p,k)$ or not, under this case.*

**Case 2:** When $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, the numerator is not divisible by $3$.  *Hence, I can conclude that $3 \nmid C(p,k)$, under this case.*

I suspect an approach similar to that done in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4191630/28816) to a tangentially related question would do the trick.

*Alas, this is where I get stuck, as I do not possess the mathematical prowess needed to conclusively settle **Case 1**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $k$ is odd and $$C(p,k)=\frac{(p^{k+1}-p^k)+3(p^k-1)}{p-1}$$
$$=p^k+3\cdot \frac{p^k-1}{p-1},$$ where the second term is divisible by $3$, hence the expression is never divisible by $3$, since $p\equiv 1~({\rm mod~}4).$

Comment: Blimey!  How could I have missed that?  Thank you for this answer, @Pythagoras!  =)